# all the links are changing if I click on one link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am new here as well as at web designing. So I know little.

In my practice web design, I have setup 5 nav links and styled them using css. This is my CSS code:

```
body {
background-color: #f9f9f9;
margin: 0;
border-top: 2px solid #020202;
color: #1c1c1c;
font-family: "arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

li {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 60px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
    width: 960px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    float: right;
}


img {
    margin-right: 150px;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
}

a {
    color: black;
}

a:visited {
    color: #15a02c;
}

a:hover {
    color: #97d586;
}


span {
    font-style: italic;
    color: #03da35;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#content img {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top: 10px
}

p {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 30px;   
}

footer img {
    width: 720px;
    height: 86px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    float: right;
}

#b_b {
    width: auto;
    height: 17px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

and this is my html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to Example 1</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li>HOME</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>WORK</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>RESUME</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>FREELANCE</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>CONTACT</li></a>                
                </ul>
                    <a href="#"><img src="twitter.jpg" alt="follow me"></a>
            </nav>
                <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                <h1>LOOKING FOR A FREELANCE FLASH/WEB DEVELOPER?</h1>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <img src="logo.jpg" alt="RINGO LOGO">
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <h2>FREELANCE FLASH & WEB DEVELOPER</h2>
                <p>Look at my <span>work</span> and my <span>resume.</span> I am <span>available</span> as <span>freelance</span> Flash & Web Developer.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img src="footer.jpg" alt="footer image">
                <div class="clear"></div>       
            </div>
        <div id="b_b"></div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now when I click one link like Home, all the links go green as if they all are visited.

Comment: You have same url in all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because all links' `href` attribute have same value: `#`.

Make them different, for example:

```
<ul>
    <a href="#home"><li>HOME</li></a>
    <a href="#work"><li>WORK</li></a>
    <a href="#resume"><li>RESUME</li></a>
    <a href="#freelance"><li>FREELANCE</li></a>
    <a href="#contact"><li>CONTACT</li></a>               
</ul>
```

Also change your unordered list (`ul`). Do not nest list items (`li`) in anchor (`a`) eventhough it works well obey to standards.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#work">WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#resume">RESUME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#freelance">FREELANCE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>           
</ul>
```

Comment: one more question if you dont mind: If I want to add a background block to the hover effect.. how can I do that? and I need that block to have padding a little bit so that it does not touch the text of the link ie Home Work and so on... and the links should not change their position. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Fix**

Change the *href* value of the links to point to other locations, like *www.google.com* and *www.stackoverflow.com* etc.

**Why**
When one link is clicked, that *destination* is stored as visited, not the *link* itself. By changing the destinations, you can fix your issue (which wouldn't show up in deployment, typically, anyway). This is required as multiple links to the same page should inform the user if they have been visited or not...